# unlist ellipsis list into variables (when unquoted) and arguments

Tags: r, function, rlang

I have the following function which works:

```
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)

hist_fun <- function(data, ...) {
  
  g <- map(
    list(data %>% 
           select(...) %>% 
           map2(., names(.), 
                ~{ggplot(data.frame(var = .x), aes(var)) + 
                    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density))) + 
                    labs(x = .y) 
                })),
    ~cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = .x, ncol = 1))
  g
}

#works
hist_fun(mtcars, mpg, cyl, disp)
```

However, I would like to be able to pass it `geom_histogram` arguments too so something like:

```
hist_fun(mtcars, mpg, cyl, disp, bins = 20, color = "white")
```

I'm not sure of the best way to approach this. Should I collect everything in the ellipsis in a list and then try to separate out the list into a) variables and b) `geom_histogram` arguments, something like:

```
hist_fun <- function(data, ...) {
  everything <- list(...)
  #unlist and extract variables/geom_histogram arguments?
  #just_vars
  #just_geom_histogram
  
  g <- map(
    list(data %>%
           select(just_vars) %>%
           map2(., names(.),
                ~{ggplot(data.frame(var = .x), aes(var)) +
                    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), just_geom_histogram) +
                    labs(x = .y)
                })),
    ~cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = .x, ncol = 1))
  g
}
```

That seems a bit messy so would it better to separate the variables at the start and keep `geom_histogram` arguments to the ellipsis, something like:

```
hist_fun(mtcars, just_vars = list(), ...)
```

Any suggestions and the best way to achieve it, particularly when I want to keep the variables unquoted?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only a small number of arguments that a user might pass to `geom_histogram`, so I would just explicitly name these in the function definition. Ensure they go *after* the ellipsis though.

```r
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)

hist_fun <- function(data, ..., color = NA, bins = 30) {
  
  g <- map(
    list(data %>% 
           select(...) %>% 
           map2(., names(.), 
                ~{ggplot(data.frame(var = .x), aes(var)) + 
                    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)),
                                   bins = bins, color = color) + 
                    labs(x = .y) 
                })),
    ~cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = .x, ncol = 1))
  g
}
```

Allowing

```r
hist_fun(mtcars, mpg, cyl, disp, bins = 10, color = "red")
```

[image]

If you didn't want to limit the user to the named arguments you decided upon, you could indeed do it by sorting through the ellipsis arguments, but it's a bit more complex:

```r
hist_fun <- function(data, ...) {
  args <- as.list(match.call())[-c(1:2)]
  named_args <- args[which(nzchar(names(args)))]
  unnamed_args <- args[which(!nzchar(names(args)))]
  hist_args <- c(list(mapping = aes(y = after_stat(density))), named_args)
  select_args <- c(list(quote(data)), unnamed_args)
  g <- map(
    list(
           map2(do.call('select', select_args), 
                names(do.call('select', select_args)), 
                ~{ggplot(data.frame(var = .x), aes(var)) + 
                    do.call('geom_histogram', hist_args) + 
                    labs(x = .y) 
                })),
    ~cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = .x, ncol = 1))
  g
}
```

For example

```r
hist_fun(mtcars, mpg, cyl, disp, bins = 15, fill = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: As an alternative for other args (I was about to post as an answer): `function(data, ..., histargs = list())` and internally `do.call(ggplot2::geom_histogram, c(list(aes(y = after_stat(density))), histargs))`. (Can also be done for `cowplot::plot_grid` if it added much.)

Comment: @r2evans I actually realised it is possible to separate out the named and unnamed arguments passed via the ellipsis, and invoke `geom_histogram` that way with only the named arguments. This seems a bit neater than passing `histargs` as a list.

Comment: I've gone that route in the past, and while it's neat (and I do keep it on occasion), it has some downsides: if the child function itself uses `...`, or if you're doing it for multiple functions and they share names, the ambiguity can be frustrating. In my experience, there is little gained from splitting the `...` when weighed against the unambiguous use of named lists (though NSE can be tricky with both).

Comment: thanks both, really useful. @r2evans just for completeness, for the method you said, is this how the function would look: `hist_fun <- function(data, ..., histargs = list()) {
  g <- map(
    list(data %>% 
           select(...) %>% 
           map2(., names(.), 
                ~{ggplot(data.frame(var = .x), aes(var)) + 
                    do.call(ggplot2::geom_histogram, c(list(aes(y = after_stat(density))), histargs)) + 
                    labs(x = .y) 
                })),
    ~cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = .x, ncol = 1))
  g
}` that doesn't seem to work for me?

Comment: Using that code, `hist_fun(mtcars, mpg, cyl, disp, histargs=list(bins = 10, color = "red"))` works for me. If it fails for you with that expression, I don't know what to say.

Comment: never mind, I had included "data" in the call! cheers